# How to camelcase a string like with Initcap but with exception of letters followed by dot?

Tags: sql, oracle

Say i have a string `ABC&EFG d.d.` , and after calling `initcap` like this

```
select initcap("ABC&EFG d.d.") from dual;
```

I would get `Abc&Efg D.D.` which is perfect for the 1st part but not what i need for the part where letters `d.d.` become `D.D.`.
So i would need a version of initcap that would not capitalize letters followed by dot.
Anyone knows if there is such posibility?

Just a clarification as i'm looking for potential built in function.

Comment: No, there is no builtin version of initcap that does what you want. I'm not sure why that's so important to you? Like most special-case requirements, you will need to put together calls to other functions (such as replace, regexp_substr, etc.) in order to do this.

Comment: Not that its important to me, its just that oracle has so much functions built in i was almost certain one such would have to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
   regexp_replace(
      initcap(
         regexp_replace('ABC&EFG d.d.', '(\w+\.)', chr(1)||'a\1')
      ), 
   chr(1)||'.') 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to filter the string for text only, it will then skip the 'd.d.' since it wont be match the regex and runs `initcap` on the matched string. Then find the 'd.d.' and concatenate it to the string after `initcap`.

```
     select initcap(REGEXP_SUBSTR('ABC'||chr(38)||'EFG d.d.','(\w\&?\w)+') ) 
|| REGEXP_SUBSTR('ABC'||chr(38)||'EFG d.d.','(\s(\w\.)+)+')  from dual;
```

Note that `REGEXP_SUBSTR` returns a single match so this might not work with more complex strings (i.e multiple matches).

Comment: why are there letters adfvv ?

Comment: These were just for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider replacing all .s with a long string of random characters (e.g. "sejvbwovbworuvybqerouyoqvuyrfwhrverhbeqorybquoyquobf"), running initcap, then replacing your random string with .s again.

```
Replace(
  InitCap(
    Replace('ABC&EFG d.d.', '.', 'sejvbwovbworuvybqero')),
  'sejvbwovbworuvybqero','.')
```

Untested!

There may be a more elegant method, mind.

Comment: Thx for the reply, but i dont want to write own function for it. I'm looking to utilize existing, built in function, if it exists and that actually is the question.